# How do I set score in a for loop, after an if, and switch statement?

Tags: java, android-studio

I am attempting to record the amount of times a user's input matches input from a text file. And if the entries are a length of 3, 4, or 5, the total score should increase by however long the user's entry is.  Instead, what happens is the score label updates each time to either 3, 4, or 5.  Any help will be greatly appreciated!

This is some code for an Android program I am currently writing:

```
try {
 reader = new BufferedReader(
  new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("Words.txt")));

 int i = 0;
 int f = 0;
 int h = 0;
 int k = 0;

 String mLine;
 String[] lines = new String[1500];
 while (((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
  lines[i] = mLine;
  i++;
 }

 for (int q = 0; q < lines.length; q++) {
  if (lines[q].contentEquals((wordEntry.getText()))) {
   int length = wordEntry.length();
   switch (length) {
    case 3:
     f++;
     continue;

    case 4:
     h++;
     continue;

    case 5:
     k++;
     continue;
   }
  } else
   score.setText("Incorrect");
 }
 int total = (f * 3) + (h * 4) + (k * 5);
 score.setText(String.valueOf(total));
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You're posting requirements and code. Much better to show your attempt to implement your functionality and tell what problems you're having with your attempt, and then use this to ask a much more specific question.  This isn't a "please do my work for me" site, or even a "please point me in the right direction" site, but rather is for much more specific questions.  Please go through the [help] and the [ask] to see how to best use this site.

Comment: Specifically, I said that I was trying to set score, (or the score label) to the value of each variable I incremented, times their corresponding number of points.  This is on the "int total" line.  How could I have been more specific?  That is not passive aggressive, I just thought my explanation was pretty clear.

Comment: SO is a terrible debugger. What have you done to figure this out? Have you followed the logic to see where it diverges from your expectations. You know the requirements and code best.  Prove your assertions, line by line. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: After reading the code, i do think this is a question worth asking. the OP said what he expect, he did wrote: int total=(f*3)+(h*4)+(k*5); And he said the result is the label gets set to 3 or 4 or 5, not the sum. I would be puzzled.

Comment: @Zuoanqh: if it's worth asking, it's worth asking well. The OP can and should improve the question, including posting a valid [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I think the below lines are what's causing the problem:

```
if (lines[q].contentEquals((wordEntry.getText()))) {
   int length = wordEntry.length();
```

What if you just did this instead?

```
int length = lines[q].length();
```

Or did you forget to tell us about something else this program is supposed to do? For example, what is `wordEntry`?

Comment: Yeah, so this is a smaller snippet of the entire program, the wordEntry is a textView component in which the user enters input from 5 buttons.  After the user makes their input, they press a "check" button for verification of whether or not their entry is listed in the array being created from the reader and its asset file.  If the entry is there, it would fulfill that if statement, meaning that wordEntry.length and lines[q].length would have the same length.  Thank you though for trying to help, and sorry for the wordiness!

Comment: I see. it seems you are not accumulating the count, since f,h,k are declared within the scope of try, which i suppose is part of the check button's code. This effectively means every time the button is clicked, f,h,k starts from 0 all over again. Put them somewhere persistent between clicks(i.e. as an attribute of the window) would solve the problem. Please follow the advice of @Hovercraft Full Of Eels as well.